# Watch output piped to /dev/null

Tags: terminal, stdout

I have a few scientific programs that can run from a few minutes up to several days.
The program prints progress information to stdout which ends in a carriage return.

If the program runs for several days I usually pipe the output to /dev/null to avoid huge logfiles.

Is there a way to periodically watch the output of the program, without having to keep all of the generated text?

Comment: What's wrong in running it in a terminal and watch anytime?

Comment: The program is often run via ssh on a compute server.
I'd like to be able to check in on it, even when it's started in the background

Comment: Can you use `tmux` or `screen` [on the server](https://superuser.com/a/1288684/432690)?

Comment: I can! Thanks, that should enable me to do what I want. @KamilMaciorowski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ssh to the server, then run `screen` to start a session. From there, launch your long-running scientific program (leaving it output normally to stdout), then disconnect anytime. Whenever you feel like watching the output, ssh back to the server again and run `screen -R` to reattach to the last detached session.

You can also use `tmux` instead of `screen`, it works similarly. Just run `tmux attach-session` instead of `screen -R`.

To do the same with an instance of your scientific program that was *not* already started in a screen session: find the program PID, then run:

```
screen
reptyr <PID>
```

to reattach it to your new screen session.

Comment: Note: `reptyr` may require adjusting `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`. If `reptyr` fails for you then see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690).

Answer (score 0):

I just developed a new solution in this exact problem area:  the [`pw` (Pipe Watch) utility](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/).

This is a small, BSD-licensed C program, less than 2000 lines in a single file, with no library dependencies, producing a small executable with a small memory footprint.

`pw` constantly reads its standard input, and so it eats everything, just like `/dev/null`. It passes the lines of input through an internal FIFO buffer, which is sampled to create an updating display.

When `pw` detects that it has been backgrounded by shell job control, it still reads its input, but doesn't refresh the display.

It's really as easy as:

```
yourlongrunningprogram | pw &
```

Then `fg` it into the foreground to view the latest output; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and `bg` to run in the background again.

`pw` has some nice interactive features: filtering, triggering, split screen operation, recall of snapshot history. The user interface is memetic of Vi: there are `:` colon commands and such. Some commands have numeric prefixes, and repeating a command is done with `.`.

Say you've been running your program for several hours or days and decide that some parts of its output are not informative. No problem, just `:v pattern` and lines not matching `pattern` are now rejected.

The most recently developed feature is that you can save the state of `pw` to a file. If you interactively set it up in a certain way, you can easily reproduce that setup from the saved file: all your filters, triggers, split screen config and other parameters.